# Is anyone else's tor not working?

Tags: torcheck

I haven't modified tor or anything and i already tried reinstalling tor but no luck. it stays stick at loading network status.

Comment: please provide your tors log output

Comment: 8/18/2016 10:43:26 AM.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
8/18/2016 10:43:26 AM.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
8/18/2016 10:43:26 AM.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
8/18/2016 10:43:26 AM.000 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150

Comment: 8/18/2016 10:43:26 AM.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
8/18/2016 10:43:27 AM.100 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
8/18/2016 10:43:27 AM.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
8/18/2016 10:43:27 AM.700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus 
8/18/2016 10:43:27 AM.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus

Comment: 8/18/2016 10:43:29 AM.200 [WARN] Our clock is 8 hours, 16 minutes behind the time published in the consensus network status document (2016-08-19 02:00:00 UTC).  Tor needs an accurate clock to work correctly. Please check your time and date settings! 
8/18/2016 10:43:29 AM.200 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
8/18/2016 10:43:30 AM.700 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150

Comment: 8/18/2016 10:43:30 AM.700 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
8/18/2016 10:43:30 AM.900 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.

Comment: `[WARN] Our clock is 8 hours, 16 minutes behind the time published in the consensus network status document (2016-08-19 02:00:00 UTC)`